# How to add one buttton2 while click another button1 and button 3 while click button2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

In the below jquery file when i click add button it create one text box with one button after i click addbutton it create another textbox with button.......But what i want is when i cllick 1st button it add 2nd button then i click 2 nd button it add 3rd button .....But  i doknow how to do ..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 2;

  $("#addButton").click(function() {
    if (counter > 10) {
      alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
      return false;
    }

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
      .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >' +
      ' <input type="button" value="Add Button"  id="addButton">');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    counter++;
  });

  $("#removeButton").click(function() {
    if (counter == 1) {
      alert("No more textbox to remove");
      return false;
    }

    counter--;
    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
  });    
});
```

Comment: Id be unique in HTML . you use addButton and addtextbox id added many times in your case. That is the reason your code not works as you expected.

Comment: Oh Thank you..But how i get this without using id..

Comment: Use common class and bind click for the class and generate the textboxes and button. it will works.

Comment: yeah thankyou it worked now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Duplicate IDs are invalid HTML and will nearly always cause issues with scripting. Avoid if at all possible.
- The click() binding you're using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach the handler to elements that already exist. It won't get bound to elements created in the future. To do that, you'll have to create a "delegated" binding by using on().
  More details: http://api.jquery.com/on/

**Your Sample:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;

  $(document.body).on('click', ".addButton", function(){

    if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
          '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >' + 
          ' <input type="button" value="Add Button" class="addButton" id="button' + counter + '">');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    $(this).attr( "disabled", "disabled" );

    counter++;
     });

     $(".removeButton").click(function () {
    if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
     }

    counter--;

        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
        $("#button" + (counter - 1)).attr( "disabled", false );
        if(counter==2){
             $(".addButton").attr( "disabled", false ); 
         }

     });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
  <input class="addButton" type="button" value="Add Button" />
  <input class="removeButton" type="button" value="Remove Button" />
</div>
<div id="TextBoxesGroup"></div>
```

Comment: The remove button already working in my snippet. Do you want to add remove button on each created group beside Add Button? Please share your code at https://jsfiddle.net/ to your understand it better.

Comment: Yeah it worked but but when i click remove button it remove last added div but i want to remove that particular div.......And my code is        https://jsfiddle.net/tfhhwfjm/

Comment: and in the same code i added textbox,checkbox,dropdown as a input filed but i need to add each as div and calling that div after the function after:html()

Comment: To remove the div replace `$("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();` with `$(this).parent().remove();` and you also do not need the code below this line with this code block. https://jsfiddle.net/tfhhwfjm/1/

Answer (score 1):

**You may try this:**

> This line `$(obj).attr( "disabled", "disabled" );` to
>   disable clicked button. You can skip.

```js
function createButton(obj){
  var $input = $('<input type="button" value="Add Button"  onclick="createButton(this);">');
  $input.appendTo($("#buttons"));
  $(obj).attr( "disabled", "disabled" ); // use it to disable clicked btn
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
  <input type="button" value="Add Button"  onclick="createButton(this);">
</div>
```